# Do I still need to create composite index explicitly if I have a composite unique constraint

Tags: sqlite

I have a table with unique constraint

```
create table if not exists watchlist(
    _id integer primary key autoincrement, 
    country text not null, 
    name text not null, 
    unique (country, name) on conflict replace
);
```

Since my query will involved `country` and `name` in WHERE clause most of the time. To speed up query, I was wondering do I still need to create

```
create index idx_country_name on watchlist(country, name);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your unique constraint will already create an implicit index, that will be created automatically by sqlite. So there is no need to create an unique index over these columns.